# SQLMap: Can't establish SSL Connection: Need Solution

Tags: sqlmap

Am trying to use SQLMap with https but when i try 
`"C:\Python27\sqlmap>sqlmap.py -u https://localhost:8774/App/console/index.jsp --force-ssl"` it returns 
**"Can't establish SSL Connection"**.

So it there any way that i can pass SSL certificate to SQLMap?

Environment Details: 
OS: Windows 10
Python: 2.7 
SQLMap: 1.4.2.42

[Refer to attached image for more details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjMeU.png)

Answer (score 1):

remove https:// from 'u' paremeter, just put:
-u localhost:8774/App/console/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for that is to **set up a proxy listener like Burp Suite**, browse over to the site with the **bad SSL certificate** and **Trust** it.

After that, you can include the following option in your **SQLMap** command:

`--proxy="http://PROXY-IP:PROXY-PORT"`

where proxy ip is generally `127.0.0.1` and proxy port `8080`.